# Scope issue with rightDown in the update method

Tags: typescript

I have some strange behavior here, in the rendered JS the value of this in the update method is window, but it should be Game (as in the onKeyDown method). How do you correct this?

```
class Game {

    //for the key events
    rightDown: bool = false;

    constructor() {

    }


    onKeyDown(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 39) this.rightDown = true;
        else if (evt.keyCode == 37) this.leftDown = true;
        if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
            this.space = true;
            var bullet = new GameObjects.GameObjects.Bullet(10);
            this.addProjectile(bullet);
        };
    }



    update(elapsed: number) {

   if (this.rightDown) {
            console.log(this.rightDown);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere else you wrote something like this:

```
setupAnimationTimer(myGame.update); // Maybe window.requestAnimationFrame ?
```

Note that you're just passing the `update` from `Game`'s prototype -- there's no pointer back to the actual `myGame` instance, thus there is no way for whoever is doing the callback to correctly invoke your `update` method with the correct `this` pointer.

If you search around there are a lot of blog posts about how `this` binding gets lost or preserved; here are two possible solutions:

```
// Create a new closure
setupAnimationTimer(() => myGame.update());
```

or

```
// Create a new function object that always invokes with the given 'this' value
setupAnimationTimer(myGame.update.bind(myGame));
```

Comment: That works because you're giving a callback which then invokes the update method off the instance. As long as you're invoking the function from the instance itself, the `this` pointer will be correct (unless it's been `bind`ed to something else, which would be really weird). A general rule of thumb is that if you refer to a method from an instance without immediately invoking it, you're going to have `this` problems.

Comment: its a shame the compiler didn't point his out to me even though I should have been aware of it.